# Algebraic structure on any infinite set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, soft-question, field-theory

Given any algebraic object $X$, say group, ring, integral domain, etc., and a special subset $I$ of $X$ namely normal subgroup, ideal etc., it is always possible to put a structure on $X/I$ induced from $X$.

Now, I will forget $I$ and the existing structure of $X$ also. I will consider $X$ as a set only.

If $X$ is finite set, then we can always give group structure or ring structure on it. The actual problem will come if $X$ is infinite set, and I don't know whether we can always make $X$ into a group or ring with some binary operations.

**Question:** Given any infinite set $S$, is it always possible to put (1) structure of group on $S$? (2) structure of ring on $S$? (3) structure of field on $S$?

Only thing I know that given any infinite set $S$, the power set of $S$ can be made into an algebra (hence group and ring structure is coming here; but where this is exactly? It is on the power set of $S$, not necessarily on $S$. Thus, in question, I stress on only set $S$ given in our hand, and try to make it a group or ring or field. Is this always possible?

Comment: Yes, yes, yes. See the [Löwenheim–Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem).

Comment: The first two paragraphs don't seem to have anything to do with the rest of the question. The first paragraph is also a bit misleading: in general, quotient objects are described by more complicated things than special subsets. For example, quotients of monoids cannot be described in terms of "normal submonoids."

Comment: First two paragraphs: I am familiar with putting structures on some new objects from structures on old objects; in algebra, I didn't see any other examples than "structure on quotient". My point was to put structure on an object, without help of other objects.

Comment: Aside: you can't put the structure of a field on a 6 element set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer all three questions it suffices to construct a field of any given infinite cardinality, since a field is a ring which is additively a group. To that effect, let $A$ be an infinite set. Then the field $\mathbb Q(A)$ of rational functions over $\mathbb Q$ using the elements of $A$ as indeterminates is a field with the same cardinality as $A$.

Comment: This is much clear, how a structure on $A$ can be given.

Comment: @p Groups: if I understand your question correctly, you need to pick a bijection between $A$ and $\mathbb{Q}(A)$, then transport the structure from the latter to the former. It's worth pointing out that the axiom of choice is required to do this: in fact the axiom of choice is equivalent to the claim that every nonempty set has a group structure (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12973/does-every-non-empty-set-admit-a-group-structure-in-zf).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, many results of this form follow from the [Löwenheim–Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem), which asserts that if a first-order theory (a particular way to write down axioms something should satisfy; this includes groups, rings, fields, and more) has an infinite model then it has a model of every infinite cardinality.

The Löwenheim–Skolem theorem has much weirder consequences than this; for example, it implies that there is a countable model of [ZF set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) (which is supposed to be a first-order theory of *all sets*), as well as an uncountable model of [(first-order) Peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) (which is supposed to be a first-order theory of the *natural numbers*).

Comment: Good answer, but to be strictly accurate I think you have to say something about the theory being countable. For instance, if you formalize the notion of a real vector space as an Abelian group augmented with uncountably many unary operations (one for scalar multiplication by each real number), there is no model of cardinality $\aleph_0.$